# Delete all elements from an array A which are present in an array B without using a double loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, loops, for-loop

So, as an input I have two arrays, A and B. Let's suppose that these are the values inside the two:

> A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] and B = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]

After the deletion the array A should be [2, 4, 6, 8, 10].

I have written (Javascript) this functioning algorithm to solve this problem:

```
for (var i=0; i < A.length; i++) {
   for (var j=0; j < B.length; j++) {
      if(B[j] == A[i]) 
         A.splice(i, 1) // Removes 1 element of the array starting from position i 
   }
}
```

I would like to know, is it possible to solve this problem without using a double loop?

Comment: This code can't work when there is no gap between 2 values in `B`  ( ex; `[1,2, 3, 5, 7, 9]`, because `2,4,6,8,10` are never tested with your actuals values in `B`)

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
let A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] ;
const B = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9];

A = A.filter(num => !B.includes(num));
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is. You could use a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set). In terms of Set operations you are computing the [difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory)#Relative_complement) `A \ B`.

Using a set which is optimized for lookups in `O(1)` time will speed up the computing the difference siginificantly from `O(n²)` when using `includes()` or double `for` loop to `O(n)`.

```js
const A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
const B = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
const setB = new Set(B);
const difference = A.filter(x => !setB.has(x));
console.log(difference);
```

Comment: interesting thank you for your answer. But how is it possible that the cost of this operation using Sets is O(1)? Don't this process has to check every element of B with every element of A anyway?

Comment: That's possible by a concept called `hashing` (**NOT** cryptographic hashing!). Maybe worth digging deeper into Data structures and algorithms, so you can understand what's going on behind the scenes. The idea is on a very hight level to compute a position of a value in an array using the value itself and some (clever) maths, so whenever we see a value we know where in an array we can find it. It's a little more complex than that though, but the idea is not to hard to understand. There's lots of material out there which can explain this to you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that ?

```js
const
  A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
, B = [1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 9]   // no gaps in 1,2 and 2,3
  ;

for (let i =0, j=0 ; i < A.length; i++)
  {
  if (A[i]===B[j]) { A.splice(i--,1); j++ }
  }
  
document.write( JSON.stringify(A) )
```

**or (faster code)**

```js
const
  A = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ]
, B = [ 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 ]
  ;

for (let i = A.length, j= B.length -1 ; i-- ; )
  {
  if (A[i]===B[j]) { A.splice(i,1); j-- }
  }
  
document.write( JSON.stringify(A) )
```